# ssh to linux through ethernet bridge to windows

Tags: networking, ssh, fedora

I have the following setup

```
                   Wifi
                /      \
               /        \
  Fedora Desktop          Windows 7 Desktop (10.0.1.16)
   (10.0.1.15)            \
                           \ <Ethernet Bridge> (192.168.137.1)
                            \
                             Raspberry Pi (Pidora) (192.168.137.6)
```

What i would like to do is to ssh to the Raspberry Pi from the Fedora PC. I can ping the Fedora PC from the Raspberry pi, but not the other way. It says destination unreachable and the return comes from the router.

How can i set up this network configuration. Do i need to add custom entries to a routing table or something?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: My guess is that you need to add an route on your win7 system

Comment: just fyi, it's not a bridge if it changes subnets. it's a router.

Comment: Is the bridge providing NAT for the Pi?  If so, no clients will be able to connect in to it.

Comment: What is that thing you're calling an "Ethernet Bridge"? Because, clearly, it's not a bridge.

Comment: Hi sorry about my absence, basically i have the pi connected to the ethernet port of my windows computer with internet sharing turned on so the pi can see the internet (windows pc has wireless), i would like to be able to ssh from the Fedora pc to the pi. The pi can see the fedora machine bu not the other way around. how can i fix this?